# scanner skipping new line

Tags: java, file

I am trying to understand the scanner class in java, does anyone why this code is only printing the first line in part one and not all the information in part 2.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BadParse {

public static String getNextEntry(InputStream in) {
    Scanner sin = new Scanner(in);

    try {
        String ssn = sin.next();
        String name = sin.next();
        int age = sin.nextInt();

        return name + "(" + ssn + ") is " + age + " years old.";
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void putNextEntry(String ssn, String name, int age, OutputStream out) {
    PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));

    pout.print(ssn + " ");
    pout.print(name + " ");
    pout.print(age + " ");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Part I
    String input = "1234567890 John 20\n0987654321 Beth 18\n2468101214 Jack 19\n";
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());

    String entry;
    while ((entry = getNextEntry(in)) != null) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }

    // Part II
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("data");

    putNextEntry("1234567890", "John", 20, out);
    putNextEntry("0987654321", "Beth", 18, out);
    putNextEntry("2468101214", "Jack", 19, out);

    out.close();
}
```

}

i tried using delimiters but to no success.

Comment: Never ignore an exception you catch.  You should at least do `e.printStackTrace()`

Answer (score 2):

If you run a debugger and step through the `getNextEntry` method, you'll see that on the second call, the `Scanner` throws a `NoSuchElementException`. The reason this is happening is because the first `Scanner` has consumed part of the `ByteArrayInputStream`.

One fix you can do is create the `Scanner` before your `while` loop and pass in the `Scanner` to `getNextEntry` instead of passing in the `ByteArrayInputStream`.

```
public static String getNextEntry(Scanner sin) {

...

Scanner sin = new Scanner(in);
String entry;
while ((entry = getNextEntry(sin)) != null) {
```

In terms of Part 2, the `PrintWriter` isn't being flushed. If you add `pout.flush()` to the bottom of `putNextEntry` that should cause data to be sent to your file. For `PrintWriter` objects, the data is only flushed if you call `println`, `printf`, `format`, or `flush`.

```
public static void putNextEntry(String ssn, String name, int age, OutputStream out) {
    PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
    pout.print(ssn + " ");
    pout.print(name + " ");
    pout.print(age + " ");
    pout.flush();
}
```

I would recommend creating and passing in the PrintWriter similar to the scanner, though. Reduces resources created and you can flush all the end after calling `putNextEntry` multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are creating `Scanner` object inside `getNextEntry` and when that object gets destroyed it closes the stream. Try passing Scanner as argument instead of stream like (and same goes for PrintWriter):

```
 import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BadParse {
public static String getNextEntry(Scanner sin) {

    try {
        String ssn = sin.next();
        String name = sin.next();
        int age = sin.nextInt();

        return name + "(" + ssn + ") is " + age + " years old.";
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void putNextEntry(String ssn, String name, int age, PrintWriter pout) {

    pout.print(ssn + " ");
    pout.print(name + " ");
    pout.print(age + " ");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Part I
    String input = "1234567890 John 20\n0987654321 Beth 18\n2468101214 Jack 19\n";
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
    Scanner sin = new Scanner(in);

    String entry;
    while ((entry = getNextEntry(sin)) != null) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }

    // Part II
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("data");
    PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));

    putNextEntry("1234567890", "John", 20, pout);
    putNextEntry("0987654321", "Beth", 18, pout);
    putNextEntry("2468101214", "Jack", 19, pout);

    pout.close();
}
}
```

Comment: ok thanks i was starting to panic, closing at the end also causes it to flush